# How to get permissions removed on files?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-management, file-sharing, homegroup

I used Windows 7 as my primary system for a long time and was sharing my libraries on homegroup. When I HAD TO format my laptop C: drive and installed Win 10, the pictures folder (On E:, non system drive, included in library) got locked and asks for administrator access. I granted it and I can see pictures now, but the security properties show an "Unknown Account" with a long alphanumeric. I set ownership, auditing and full control to my account. Then, for the sake of confirmation, I reset my PC, and I found that "Unknown account" is back and the permissions are like before. How do I get rid of every permissions/Auditing/Ownership? Is there a way to make the files completely normal?

Answer (score 0):

The 'Unknown Account' was the account you had previously granted permissions to the drive/folder/file. Reformatting your drive and installing a new Windows operating system results in a new user (even if you use the same name when creating the account.) The long string of characters is the Security Identifier (SID) that was associated with the original account.

Likewise, when you reset your PC, the new account would have a different SID.

Taking ownership of the folder and subfolder, then resetting the permissions to the account/group that you want to have access will grant the user/group permissions that you specify.

If you want to remove the 'Unknown Account':

In Windows Explorer, right click on the folder you want to manage;

- Select Properties
- Select Security tab
- Select the Advanced option
- Find the 'Unknown Account'
- Click on Remove and apply to all folders and subfolders (if prompted)

Comment: I did that, I removed the Unknown account, but then, after resetting, I cannot open the files unless I do what you said again. It is not the case with other folders though.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Make sure that you are logged in as an administrator.

Step 2: Try to take ownership of the files and check if it helps.

Taking ownership of a folder from explorer

1)       Locate the file or folder on which you want to take ownership in windows explorer.
 2)       Right click on file or folder and select “Properties” from Context Menu.
 3)       Click on "Security" tab.
 4)       Click on “Advanced” button.
 5)       Now click on "Owner" tab in Advanced Security Settings for User windows.
 6)       Click on Edit Button and select user from given Change Owner to list if user or group is not in given list.
 7)       Click on other users or groups. Enter name of user/group and click ok.
 8)       Now select User/group and click apply and ok. Check “Replace owner on subcontainers and objects” if you have files and folder within selected folder.
 9)       Click ok when Windows Security Prompt is displayed.
 10)     Now Owner name must have changed.
 11)     Now click Ok to exist from Properties windows.

Once you have taken the ownership of file or folder next part comes is granting permissions to that file/folder or object.
 If the above method doesn’t work, you could try taking ownership from the command line.

Or  Taking ownership of a file or folder from command line

Open an elevated Command Prompt window.

To do so:

a. Go to > Start > All Programs > Accessories

b. Right-click on Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator.

c. Type the following command and press Enter key:

takeown /f [path to folder] /r /d y

d. To assign the Administrators group Full Control Permissions for the folder, use this command and hit Enter key:

icacls [path to folder] /grant administrators:F /T

The /T parameter is added so that the operation is carried out through all the sub-directories and files within that folder.